# Linux tee command occasionally fails if followed by a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, tee

I run a find command with tee log and xargs process output; by accident I forget add `xargs` in second pipe and found this question.

The example:

```
% tree
.
├── a.sh
└── home
    └── localdir
        ├── abc_3
        ├── abc_6
        ├── mydir_1
        ├── mydir_2
        └── mydir_3

7 directories, 1 file
```

and the content of `a.sh` is:

```
% cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
LOG="/tmp/abc.log"

find home/localdir -name "mydir*" -type d  -print | tee $LOG | echo
```

If I add the second pipe with some command, such as `echo` or `ls`, the write log action would occasionally fail.

These are some examples when I ran `./a.sh` many times:

```
% bash -x ./a.sh; cat /tmp/abc.log  // this tee failed
+ LOG=/tmp/abc.log
+ find home/localdir -name 'mydir*' -type d -print
+ tee /tmp/abc.log
+ echo


% bash -x ./a.sh; cat /tmp/abc.log  // this tee ok
+ LOG=/tmp/abc.log
+ find home/localdir -name 'mydir*' -type d -print
+ tee /tmp/abc.log
+ echo

home/localdir/mydir_2  // this is cat /tmp/abc.log output
home/localdir/mydir_3
home/localdir/mydir_1
```

Why is it that if I add a second pipe with some command (and forget `xargs`), the `tee` command will fail occasionally?

Comment: Why you add echo after pipe.. i think tee already works fine.

Comment: @LeeHoYo echo is only for example, I run this command with xargs, but by accident I forget write xargs and found this problem, so I want to know why would cause this.

Comment: @TankyWoo, but echo **does not read `stdin`** so once the pipe fills up, it will block all the pipeline (or if you use the echo internal bash command, you'll get probably an error, as echo doesn't read anything)

Comment: @LuisColorado block the pipeline is one of the result, such as replace `echo` with `sleep 1`, but it can write to file. See my answer.

Comment: @TankyWoo, if you replace `echo` with `sleep 1` (which also doesn't read data from stdin) as has been explained, as soon as it finishes, the process that feeds it with input will be signalled by the kernel and return with a `broken pipe` message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `tee` exits when a write to a pipe fails.  So, consider:

```
find home/localdir -name "mydir*" -type d  -print | tee $LOG | echo
```

If `echo` completes first, the pipe will fail and `tee` will exit.     The timing, though, is imprecise.  Every command in the pipeline is in a separate subshell.  Also, there are the vagaries of buffering.  So, sometimes the log file is written before `tee` exits and sometimes it isn't.

For clarity, let's consider a simpler pipeline:

```
$ seq 10 | tee abc.log | true; declare -p PIPESTATUS; cat abc.log
declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0")'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ seq 10 | tee abc.log | true; declare -p PIPESTATUS; cat abc.log
declare -a PIPESTATUS='([0]="0" [1]="141" [2]="0")'
$
```

In the first execution, each process in the pipeline exits with a success status and the log file is written.  In the second execution of the same command, `tee` fails with exit code `141` and the log file is not written.

I used `true` in place of `echo` to illustrate the point that there is nothing special here about `echo`.  The problem exists for any command that follows `tee` that might reject input.

#### Documentation

Very recent versions of `tee` have an option to control the pipe-fail-exit behavior.  From `man tee` from coreutils-8.25:

> --output-error[=MODE]
>               set behavior on write error.  See MODE below

The possibilities for MODE are:

> MODE determines behavior with write errors on the outputs:
>
> ```
>    'warn' diagnose errors writing to any output
>
>    'warn-nopipe'
>           diagnose errors writing to any output not a pipe
>
>    'exit' exit on error writing to any output
>
>    'exit-nopipe'
>           exit on error writing to any output not a pipe
> ```
>
> The  default  MODE  for the -p option is 'warn-nopipe'.  The default
>   operation when --output-error is not specified, is to exit immediately
>   on  error writing to a pipe, and diagnose errors writing to non pipe
>   outputs.

As you can see, the default behavior is *"to exit immediately
on  error writing to a pipe"*.  Thus, if the attempt to write to the process that follows `tee` fails before `tee` wrote the log file, then `tee` will exit without writing the log file.

Comment: The writing to `echo`'s standard input won't fail until `echo` exits and `tee` attempts to write again.  The `echo` may exit rather quickly, and the `tee` may spend time waiting for input before writing to standard output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK.  That is likely here and I updated the answer..  I also tested `seq 100000 | tee abc.log | sleep 10` and obtained the same intermittent results even though `sleep` is long-lived.  In this case, it appears to me that, when the input buffer for sleep fills, tee can no longer write even though sleep is still active, and this triggers the fail.

Comment: When the pipe fills, `tee` is prevented from writing any more to the pipe (it is blocked in the last `write` call) until the 'reading' process (`sleep` or `echo`, neither of which actually reads its standard input) reads something, or terminates (or otherwise closes its standard input, so there is no process left reading the standard output of `tee`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes.

Comment: @John1024 The pipe is not series execution? it should wait tee execution complete and then fork a new subshell?

Comment: @John1024 Additional to your answer: `--output-error` option not found in coreutils-8.23, but found in coreutils-8.25

Comment: @TankyWoo Thank you for the information on output-error and coreutils version.  Answer updated.  As for pipes, on Unix anyway, no, processes are not run succession: they run in parallel.   This is important when pipes are used to provide continuous output.  It also allows pipes to handle very large quantities of data without having to write it to disk at each step.

Comment: @TankyWoo: No — a pipeline is not serialized execution. A pipeline uses concurrent execution of the programs.  It must; the pipes have a finite and quite small capacity (traditionally 5 KiB, but often 64 KiB on modern systems), so if the data flowing down a pipe is more than that size, it is crucial that the programs execute concurrently as otherwise, the writing process will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged the `tee` source code, but I'm not familiar with Linux C, so maybe have problems.

`tee` belongs to coreutils package, under `src/tee.c`

First, it set buffer with:

```
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // for standard output
setvbuf (descriptors[i], NULL, _IONBF, 0);  // for file descriptor
```

So it is unbuffer?

Second, tee put stdout as its **first** item in descriptor array, and will write to descriptor with for loop:

```
/* In the array of NFILES + 1 descriptors, make
   the first one correspond to standard output.   */
descriptors[0] = stdout;
files[0] = _("standard output");
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

...

  for (i = 0; i <= nfiles; i++) {
    if (descriptors[i]
        && fwrite (buffer, bytes_read, 1, descriptors[i]) != 1)  // failed!!!
      {
        error (0, errno, "%s", files[i]);
        descriptors[i] = NULL;
        ok = false;
      }
    }
```

such as `tee a.log`, descriptors[0] is stdout, and descriptors[1] is a.log.

As @John1024 said, pipeline is **parallel** (what I misunderstand before). The second pipe command, such as `echo`, `ls`, or `true`, **not accept `input`, so it would not "wait" for the input**, and if it execute faster, it will close the pipe (**input end**) before **tee write to output end**, so above code, the comment line will failed not not go on writing to file descriptor.

---

Supply:

The `strace` result with `killed by SIGPIPE`:

```
write(1, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n", 21) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=22649, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this, as it's mostly a red herring, but the insight at the end that this was a waste of effort is valuable, and I'm sure it was spent with the best of intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Right, piping from tee to something that exits early (not dependent on reading the input from tee in your case) will cause intermittent errors.
For a summary of this gotcha see:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/coreutils-gotchas.html#tee